# Rails: Nested paths view convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the Rails ["Getting Started"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles) guide and noticed an interesting differentiation in the code for determining a link path.
For the parent model, `article`, we have:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), 
  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And for the child model, `comment`, we have:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
 method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

These seem to be very different formats for a link to a model in similar circumstances. Is there an explanation - technical or methodology-related? I'm especially curious why an array of 2 items is needed for `comment`.

Lastly, my inheritance instincts tell me the code should be `article.comment` instead of `comment.article`. Any reasoning behind this ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to **@hashrocket** answer, It all comes down to how Rails creates routes for *nested resources*. If run `rake routes` you would see this

```
article         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)   articles#destroy

article_comment DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format) comments#destroy
```

That means, a *delete request for an article* just takes `:id` as *key/parameter*, whereas the *delete request for comment needs two*, `article_id`(*the `:id` of the article that particular comment belongs to*) and the `:id` of the comment itself.

In simple terms, to delete an article, you just need its `:id` so it is `article_path(article)`, whereas to delete a comment you need the `:id`(which serves for `:article_id`) of the article it belongs to and the `:id` of the comment,so it is `[comment.article, comment]`. You can also write it as `article_comment_path(comment.article, comment)`

I suggest you to read about [*nested resources*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to understand better

Answer (score 2):

A little earlier in the guide, you can see they  setup up some associations between an article and a comment. An article has many comments and a comment belongs to an article.

The reason there is an array for the deletion of the comment is because you have to know the article the comment belongs to and the comment itself because of those associations. Since comments belong to articles, we need the article id to find the comment we want to delete. That's why it's comment.article. We're finding the article the comment belongs to.

If you write article.comment, you're getting a comment of the article, not an article of the comment.